# Google Location Services API, not accurate location

Tags: android, api, location

I am using the following code to get accurate location of user, however I have to say that location is not accurate. It varies within 30meters which is not acceptable if you wanna get exact location for crucial purposes. I use the code below (followed a tutorial) to get the accurate location however it's not precise. Any hints on how to get more preferably 100% accurate position.

Activity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_location);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Nieuwe Locatie Toevoegen");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;

    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch(Exception ex) {}

    try {
        network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch(Exception ex) {}

    if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
        // notify user
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Enable Gps Location plaeast");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Ja ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                //get gps
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Nee liever niet", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    if (checkGooglePlayServices()) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();

        //prepare connection request
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

private boolean checkGooglePlayServices() {

    int checkGooglePlayServices = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (checkGooglePlayServices != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
          /*
           * google play services is missing or update is required
           *  return code could be
           * SUCCESS,
           * SERVICE_MISSING, SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED,
           * SERVICE_DISABLED, SERVICE_INVALID.
           */
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(checkGooglePlayServices,
                this, REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES).show();

        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() &&
                    !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services must be installed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
       //
       // Toast.makeText(this, "Latitude:" + mLastLocation.getLatitude()+", Longitude:"+mLastLocation.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude(), 1);
            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();

            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setMessage("You locatie momenteel is : "+ " " + address + " " + city + " " + postalCode);
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Ja dit klopt", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Stad:" + city + " Straat: "+ address + " Postcode :" + postalCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    startLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
// Second Part

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(20000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Update -> Latitude:" + mLastLocation.getLatitude()+", Longitude:"+mLastLocation.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what permission is set in manifest ?

use FINE_LOCATION instead of COARSE_LOCATION for more accurate/precise location
    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: Acces_fine_location i use! @K00lkaM

Comment: if you are still seeing the same issue, please follow the [link](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)  for google map utils app which has all google api's working with map's and location